# The use of 'of' at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions, functions

Besides expressing the relationship between a part and a whole, recently I found another interesting use of preposition 'of':

> Mr Harper's call for a rise in interest rates should not surprise us. When the national economy is growing fast, many economics analysts will claim that interest rates should rise to prevent a situation of boom and bust. **Of** greater surprise are his optimistic long-term projections for growth in the Australian manufacturing sector.

What is the significance of placing 'of' at the beginning of the sentence? Is it still used as a preposition in the sentence?

Comment: The passage states that Mr. Harper has done one thing which is _not_ surprising, but something else he has done _is_ a source of surprise. The phrase has been placed at the beginning of the sentence to emphasise it.

Comment: A prepositional phrase may be used after _be_: The books are on the table. // Inversion is allowable: 'On the corner stood [/was] a large, impressive statue of the famous general' [[pearsonlongman.com...grammar](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00056.htm)]. Similarly, 'Of greater surprise are his optimistic long-term projections ...'. In fact, 'of greater surprise' probably sounds more natural when fronted.